# brightest single LED running off of a 9v battery

Tags: led

I need help finding an LED to work with my project(if I told you what it is you'd say I was stupid, which has already been established by basically everyone). Here's the important stuff;

- It is going to be powered by a [GP SUPERCELL Super Heavy Duty 1604s 6f22 9v battery](https://finddealsfor.me/dealextreme/769/gp-supercell-9v-battery-white-aka-1604s-6f22) that I salvaged from a broken multimeter.
- The LED must be able to remain on for up to three seconds without any risk of overheating or breaking. Assume a break of at least one second between the next strobe.
- It must be able to fit in a tube with an inner diameter of 7 mm(does not include the leads)
- If needed, the power supply can be changed, but only as a last resort
- Overall life before the battery dies needs to be at least five minutes of 'on' time
- Is preferably white light, but yellowed light is OK. RGB LEDs and colored LEDs will not be used.
- Taking apart a flashlight is doable
- no more than $5 in cost

If it follows these requests, then please post a link and lumens and I'll use the brightest one from the answers. Thanks!

Comment: In general, white LEDs require 3 V. In order to drive an LED _efficiently_ from a 9 V battery (without wasting 2/3 of the energy as heat), you're going to need a DC-DC converter module as well as an LED.

Comment: @KevinReid, that sounds pricey and like it takes up a bit of space. I'm fine with the inefficiency.

Comment: Take two AAA battery - 2*AAA is 3 volts. The power capacity depends on the volume and will not be much worse.